# simulate Daemon-set in kubernetes with using Deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to simulate Daemon-set in kubernetes with using Deployment/RC/Replica-set.

**What I want to achieve :**

As daemon-set kind deploy PODs on each nodes like wise I want to deploy pod on each node, but without kind daemonset.

Is there any way to do it ? Can't find proper way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using Deployment/ReplicaSet in Kubernetes with **hostPort**.
Assuming you have 4 nodes in Kubernetes cluster, you can create a deployment or replicaset with hostPort and replicas equal to number of nodes in cluster. 
For example you want to run nginx pod on every node with clustersize equal to 4 then you have mention hostport to container port in deployment/replicaset definition. The kubernetes scheduler will be unable to schedule more than 1 pod on same host and in this way all nodes have at least one pod scheduled.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-hello
  labels:  
    tier: frontend
    app: nginx-hello
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: frontend
        app: nginx-hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-hello
        image: nginxdemos/hello
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 8088
```

Comment: you can also this usecase to schedule on multizone kubernetes cluster using setbased label condition For example  2 nodes in two zone zoneA and zoneB environment=production, zone in (zoneA , zoneB)

Comment: But, if one of your `node` is `NotReady`, there must be more than one `pod` with `hostPort` in one `node`, which MUST fail to start the second pod, because the `hostPort` has been occupied.

Comment: And k8s won't start new `pod` in the new node unless you add or reduce  `replicas` when the number of `Ready Nodes` changed.

Comment: But the requirement is to schedule one pod per node.so even if node is notready the pod will not be scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more use cases here

http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/

Two containers using the same hostPort cannot be scheduled on the same node and the usage of the hostPort is considered a privileged.
Hence it has some limitations like

1) no. of replicas should not be more than no. of nodes which will exhaust hostports :)

2) all hosts must be in healthy state so that schedular can schedule pods on each of them.

Hope it help you.....